# Unable to read image text with python tesseract and OpenCV help me

Tags: python, operating-system, ocr, captcha, recaptcha-v3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZNxd.png)import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

## Function to enhance image

def enhance_img(filename):
# Open the image
im = Image.open(filename)

```
# Enhance image and save under a new name
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')

# Save the enhanced image with a new filename
newfilename = filename[:-4] + '_enhanced.png'
im.save(newfilename)
```

## Path to your image file

image_path = "C:/Users/ws_htu1000/OneDrive - Hoonartek/Pictures/ram/captcha_image_processed.png"

## Enhance the image

enhance_img(image_path)

## Open the enhanced image file

enhanced_image_path = "C:/Users/ws_htu1000/OneDrive - Hoonartek/Pictures/ram/captcha_image_processed_enhanced.png"
img = Image.open(enhanced_image_path)

## Use pytesseract to do OCR on the enhanced image

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

## Print the extracted text

print("Extracted Text:", text)

[this image i want to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw9vm.png)

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

## Function to enhance image

def enhance_img(filename):
# Open the image
im = Image.open(filename)

```
# Enhance image and save under a new name
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')

# Save the enhanced image with a new filename
newfilename = filename[:-4] + '_enhanced.png'
im.save(newfilename)
```

## Path to your image file

image_path = "C:/Users/ws_htu1000/OneDrive - Hoonartek/Pictures/ram/captcha_image_processed.png"

## Enhance the image

enhance_img(image_path)

## Open the enhanced image file

enhanced_image_path = "C:/Users/ws_htu1000/OneDrive - Hoonartek/Pictures/ram/captcha_image_processed_enhanced.png"
img = Image.open(enhanced_image_path)

## Use pytesseract to do OCR on the enhanced image

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

## Print the extracted text

print("Extracted Text:", text)